# Legacy Web Forms project open in VS 2015 not stepping into if statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Visual Studio 2012 Web Forms project open in Visual Studio 2015. My issue occurs in the code behind on a login button click. I'm trying to debug the code in the button click, but when I reach the first `if` statement and attempt to step into the code, the debugger skips over the whole section even if the conditions are true and moves into the second `if` statement just fine. The two text boxes definitely have text in both of them, I've made sure of that.

When previously debugging the code in VS 2012, this issue never happened. It is only happening in VS 2015.

Below I have included the code:

**Login.aspx HTML:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserId" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="100%" TabIndex="1" PlaceHolder="Email"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" Width="100%" TabIndex="2" PlaceHolder="Password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<br/>
<a runat="server" onserverclick="btnLogin_Click" class="ghost-button">Log-In</a>
```

**Login.aspx code behind:**

```
    protected async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //the if statement in question
        if ((txtUserId.Text != "") && (txtPassword.Text != ""))
        {
            await Login(txtUserId.Text, txtPassword.Text);
        }

        if (Session["AuthToken"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Dash.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {
            txtUserId.Text = "";
            txtPassword.Text = "";
            lblUserError.Text = "Username and/or password is invalid";
        }
    }

    public async Task Login(string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var email = "";
            string token;
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_serviceUrl);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

                var responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync("Token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                    new[] {
                    new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("username", username),
                    new KeyValuePair < string, string > ("password", password)
                }

                    ));
                var tokenModel = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenModel>();
                token = tokenModel.AccessToken;
            }

            Session["AuthToken"] = token;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate any help that can be given. I will update the question if/when more information is required.

Comment: What if you (for a test) remove the async await statement? It seems like that would cause the debugger to go past it.

Comment: for the sake of debugging, do this:  `var myCondition = (txtUserId.Text != "") && (txtPassword.Text != "")` and `if(myCondition)`  to make sure that the condition **really** is true.  alternatively, you can type `(txtUserId.Text != "") && (txtPassword.Text != "")` directly into the watch window

Comment: @Regency Software The awaited method is required for login. I added it to help explain, its a HttpClient call to a REST service.

Comment: @SamIam After editing the code as you ask `var myCondition = (txtUserId.Text != "") && (txtPassword.Text != "")` the debugger hits that particular line of code, then progresses as if I hit `F5` to complete debugging.

Comment: @ratman  it sounds like it's throwing an exception.  Check your debugger and see what `txtUserId.Text` and `txtPassword.Text` are.  if you want to be sure to break on exceptions, press ctrl+alt+e in visual studio and check the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" checkbox

Comment: @SamIam I did as you asked and got the following:

Exception thrown: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\~AspAccessCheck_7ce8ea4311144.tmp' is denied.

Searching for this error, the closest thing I could find was to update my Nuget packages and after doing that, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @ratman I'm not entirely sure what causes an exception like that to happen, but that's probably what's been happening in your application